# Deploy .Net Web API to Azure App Service using GitHub Actions and include email template file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a .Net Web API project for which I have configured CI/CD using Github actions, it is being deployed on Azure App service. Recently, I have setup an endpoint that sends an email using a .htm template, since this template cannot be resolved in deployed API, this endpoint throws an error -

`Could not find a part of the path C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\EmailTemplates\\OtpValidation.htm'.`

I checked scm in app service and was not able to find the template. I'm not sure how can I include a particular file when deploying through GitHub Actions.

Repository - https://github.com/Jatinchhabra21/bookkeeper-api

Deployed swagger - https://bookkeeper.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html

API endpoint - /api/users/new/otp

Comment: you should access it using virtual path. Try EmailTemplates\OtpValidation.htm only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Thiago Custodio for your comments.

In your **`.csproj`** file add the below code to copy the EmailTemplates folder to output directory always.

**`.csproj file:-`**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="EmailTemplates\OtpValidation.htm">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Utility\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Also, In your Program.cs make sure you enable static serving by adding > **`app.UseStaticFiles`** option like below:-

I created one **`Asp.NET Core API`** with **`.Net 7.0  runtime`** and created one folder with EmailTemplates by adding OtpValidation.htm and your code inside it, Then I edited my Program.cs to serve the OtpValidation.htm like below:-

**My Folder:-**

[image]

**My Program.cs:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Configure static file serving from the EmailTemplates folder
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "EmailTemplates")), // Adjust the path as needed
    RequestPath = "/EmailTemplates" // Virtual path to access files
});

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

I added this code to my Github Repository and used  github action workflow below that build and Deploys the entire dotnet api in Azure Web app:-

Open your solution in the Visual Studio and Publish it via Github Actions Workflow CI/CD like below:-

[image]

***Github Action workflow got created and ran successfully like below:-***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I had to ask one more thing, in csproj file you include OtpValidation file specifically, in future if I include multiple templates do I need to add them manually or I could simply include EmailTemplates folder and it would be included automatically (since I'm including the parent folder itself)?

Comment: Glad it helped, If the templates are in a parent folder then they will be build together and you won't need to add the parameter in .csproj file, But incase any template fails to built, You can just reference that template in .csproj manually. As it is not added by default.